# what is resources?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-resources

what is difference between `<resources>` and `<Linearlayout>`? what is `<resources>` and where do we use it? 
I searched and i see android site but i dont understand that what is `<resources>`.

why in `strings.xml` we use `<resources>`?
for example, in this code we use  so why not use `<LinearLayout>`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="difficulty">
        <item>@string/easy_label</item>
        <item>@string/medium_label</item>
        <item>@string/hard_label</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Cheers.

Comment: LinearLayout is use when you design a layout. Resources are things you use in your application like Strings, images, ....<br>
Regarding Layouts [Please refer here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) Regarding resources [Please refer here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html)

Comment: Resources basically refer to the resources that you make for your android project and store in res folder. You can access these resources through R.java file. Difference between resources and linear layout is linear layout defines a layout format. Strings.xml is a resource file. Resources kept in here can be accesed through R.strings.yourStringName. For more details refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html

Comment: please have some book or online tutorials on Android. At least have some moment at http://developer.android.com/

Answer (score 2):

Resources basically refer to the resources that you make for your android project and store in res folder. You can access these resources through R.java file. Difference between resources and linear layout is linear layout defines a layout format. 
Strings.xml is a resource file. Resources kept in here can be accesed through R.strings.yourStringName. For more details refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html